# SQL WHILE (String manipulation)

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, while-loop

I got a text string consists of 38 chars or so, and i want to search for that string in the database in a specific column. If there is a match, i want the corresponding value from another column as result. If no match is found, i want the string to get cut off by one char from the right hand side, and a new match search performed. This should repeat until either a match if found OR i'm running out of characters

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

This is the code i made so far, but it's not really doing what i expect it to:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ITEM VARCHAR(38)
DECLARE @CTR INT = 0
DECLARE @RES VARCHAR(40)

SET @ITEM = 'KLS3055P3H01T01A3913 STDP STDP V2 SOMO'
SET @RES = NULL
WHILE @RES IS  NULL
BEGIN
  SET @RES = (SELECT A.a_nr FROM spekgbp.dbo.art A WHERE A.a_bet LIKE @ITEM)
  SET @ITEM = LEFT(@ITEM, LEN(@ITEM)-1)
  SET @CTR = @CTR + 1
  IF (@CTR =10)
  BREAK
END
SELECT @RES as 'RES', @ITEM as 'ITEM'
```

Comment: Could you tell me why do you use the LIKE operator? If you need an exact match, you should use =. If you need the LIKE logic, then you should concatenate the @ITEM with a '%'

Comment: Also, the SELECT may return many values. If you need only 1, you should protect yourself in some way.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: GeorgiG! I just think you solved my problem! LIKE operator is clearly not the correct OPERATOR in this code. I just changed it to = and i got the expected result. Thanks so much for finding my flaw.
The code is not failsafe, just as you wrote, it may return too many values. There "should" only be unique, but the field is not unique.

Comment: @AxiAngel For some strange reason, LIKE does not work as expected when I add '%' to the string. It operates as if % replaces [one or many] characters instead of [any character].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my proposal, if I understand you correctly:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ITEM VARCHAR(38)
DECLARE @CTR INT = 0
DECLARE @RES VARCHAR(40)

SET @ITEM = 'KLS3055P3H01T01A3913 STDP STDP V2 SOMO'
SET @RES = NULL

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
SET @RES = (SELECT MIN(A.a_nr) FROM spekgbp.dbo.art A WHERE A.a_bet = @ITEM)
IF (@RES IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
SET @ITEM = LEFT(@ITEM, LEN(@ITEM)-1)
SET @CTR = @CTR + 1
IF (@CTR = 10)
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
END

SELECT @RES as 'RES', @ITEM as 'ITEM'
```

I added the infinate loop, because when match is found @ITEM is still cut at the end, and in my way loop breaks immediately after @RES is found.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that too, but you certainly beat me to it. I had to change the value [IF (@CTR = 10] to 30 just to get a thorough search (to avoid it stopping too early)